# Sorting python by value in a value dict

Tags: python, sorting

Given a dictionary:

```
d = {'a':{'priority': 10}, 'b': {'priority':20}}
```

Can I return the keys in a sorted order by priority (in a dict in the value)?

Something like:

```
>>> print sorted_list
['b', 'a']
```

Comment: do you need to sort with respect to priority or will there be any other keys

Comment: Sorry, there are other keys, but priority will be the one I sort on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure.

```
sorted_list = sorted(d.keys(), key=lambda i: d[i]['priority'], reverse=True)
```

Comment: I knew lambda would be the key... Looking that up now... Thanks

Answer (score 6):

By giving `sorted` a key to sort by, in this case `'priority'`

```
sorted(d, key=lambda e: d[e]['priority'], reverse=True)
```